# Preventing Hover event of a Div triggering on parent Div?

Tags: css, html, hover

When I mouseover `.mensal` DIV it will trigger the mouseover the parent `.opera` DIV, which seems wrong to me. I just want the "highlight" effect to to work on the child `.opera` DIV.

```css
#operaContent {
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}
#operaContent .opera {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #0A8ECC;
}
#operaContent .opera:hover {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mensal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 8px;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="operaContent">
  <div class="opera">
    <div class="mensal">
      DIV
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By definition, hovering over a child, hovers over the parent as well.  There is no "blocking" in html events.

There are two method chains, the bubble and the capture.

> Any event taking place in the W3C event model is first captured until
>   it reaches the target element and then bubbles up again.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

The only way you're going to stop this is to prevent the bubbling by adding javascript to your page to prevent the chain.  This is simple in jQuery

```
$('.mensal').hover(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

It occurs to me that this answer is completely unhelpful when dealing with CSS.  Javascript events dont deal with CSS selectors or preventing them.

Unfortunately, with CSS alone, I do not know of a way to accomplish this (and even in javascript it can get tricky).  CSS 4 selectors will allow you to specify the subject of the selector http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject so that you can do something like

```
 #operaContent .opera:hover! .mensal:not(:hover) { /*your css*/ }
```

but this isnt implemented yet, and is still under development for the draft.

EDIT:
Here is a javascript (jQuery) implementation that should work for you

​

```
$(function(){
    $('.opera').hover(function() {$(this).addClass('hoverIntent')}, 
                      function(){ $(this).removeClass('hoverIntent'); }
                     );

    $('.opera .mensal').hover(function() {
        $(this).parent('.opera').removeClass('hoverIntent');
    });

})​
```

and the modified CSS

```
#operaContent {
    padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}

#operaContent .opera {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #0A8ECC;
}


#operaContent .opera.hoverIntent {
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mensal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 8px;
    z-index: 3;
    display: block;
}​
```

and the obligitory working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WB6Ty/

Comment: Thank  you for your quick response.
I've added the suggested code but doesn't work! :(
"hovering" in .mensal div still hovers the parent div.

Comment: are you using jQuery?  try returning false from the method.  Also, just noticed a typo, fixing the answer now.  The hover is a function call, so it needs to be closed :)

Comment: ive added a javascript implementation with some modified css that should help

Comment: Don't you mean stopPropagation instead of preventDefault?

Comment: @j08691 yes.  Thats correct.  To stop bubbling, you want http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ not http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/  good catch.