# CSS selector li:hover for only when none of its child is hovered

Tags: css, css-selectors

Say I have the HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS

```
li { padding-left: 20px; background-image: url(arrow.png); }
li:hover { background-image: url(arrow-hover.png); }
```

I want to change the background-image back to arrow.png when `li > a` is hovered.
I am looking for something like this.

```
li:hover:not(this > a:hover) { background-image: url(arrow-hover.png); }
```

Comment: i think you cant do that without javascript ;/

Comment: Possible duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364511/preventing-hover-event-of-a-div-triggering-on-parent-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to do this in CSS3. (Thanks Oswaldo and Evan)

If anyone looking for similar solution, I had to use this JavaScript.

```
$("li").hover(function () { $(this).addClass('hover'); },
              function () { $(this).removeClass('hover'); });
$("li > *").hover(function () { $(this).parent().removeClass('hover'); },
                  function () { $(this).parent().addClass('hover'); });
```

and change the CSS selector from `li:hover` to `li.hover` (or any class you use above)

```
li.hover { background-image: url(arrow-hover.png); }
```

Answer (score 0):

actually ,when you will hover on  tag inside li ,,it will trigger two hover actions ..one for the parent li and the other for  tag ,,you may try to make

```
li >a:hover { background-image: url(arrow-hover.png) !important; }
```

it's not tested but you can try it ...

Answer (score 0):

t's been a while since I jQuery'd but

```
$("li > a").hover(
  function(){
    $this.parent("li").css("background-image", "url(arrow-hover.png)")
  },
  function(){
    $this.parent("li").css("background-image", "url(arrow.png)")
  }
);
```