# CSS or JS Rule for all Divs to Change BG Color of Div inside Div, Without Changing Parent Div

Tags: javascript, css, hover, mouseover

I know it seems trivial, but I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around this.

```
<div id="divA" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: #FF0000;">
    <div id="divB" style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: #FFFF00;">
        <div id="divC" style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #FF00FF;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need is a rule that applies to all divs, like div:hover { background-color: #000000 !important; }, that only affects the first parent div of the event (when I hover divC, I want the background color of divC to change to black, but not the background colors of divB or divA)... like the inspector does in Google Chrome.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it's posible in CSS. For a jquery solution, see [http://stackoverflow.com/q/10364511/1926369]

Comment: It's definitely not possible in CSS *yet*. If you hover a child, you are automatically also hovering its parent by its very definition. The CSS working group is actually working on the targeting specification, allowing you to specify parent elements in a selector chain, but that is not implemented by any browser yet (nor soon planned).

Comment: [Some reading on the subject](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/). I'm trying to find the W3 proposals that are currently going around (wildly different syntax from what's displayed here).

Comment: [Here it is](http://www.red-team-design.com/css-parent-selector). It's suggested for CSS4, and *currently* the syntax consensus appears to be `parent! child`, meaning *"if there is an element child within parent, apply this rule to the parent since it is followed by the `!` character"*. It implies that the `!` is defaulted to the last element of the selector. Once it's in you could use `div! div:hover` to solve your problem, but CSS4 isn't going to be happening before 2015 at the very least.

Comment: I'll just keep spamming a bit since people appear to find it interesting  :)  [Current CSS4 working draft over at W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) actually switches the `!` to the front of the subject element, so like `!div div:hover`. I think this makes sense to keep it from confusing structural selector chains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t believe it is possible to do this with just CSS, but you can with JavaScript.

The key is to use **`event.stopPropagation()`** on the **mouseover** event.

Here is an example using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/K96DS/2/

```
$('div').on('mouseover', function(){

    $(this).addClass('hovered')

    // this is the key, this stops te mouover event
    // from bubbling up to the parent elements
    event.stopPropagation(); 

}).on('mouseout', function(){

    $(this).removeClass('hovered')

})
```

Comment: I'll give this a try. Looks promising. I'll accept after testing.

Comment: Promising? It does exactly what you asked for. Click the link to jsfiddle

Comment: LOL, okay. Give me a second.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking using something like .this because of an odd behavior in :hover?

```
  .mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j8ebE/2/) ?

***jQuery Solution:***

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).on({
        mouseover:function(){
          $(this).css('background-color','black');  
        },
        mouseout:function(){
          $(this).css('background-color','');  
        }
    });          
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8ebE/2/

Answer (score -4):

```
#divC:hover #divA { background-color: #FF0000 !important; }
#divC:hover #divB { background-color: #FFFF00 !important; }
```

Maybe hacks... :)

Comment: These rules will never trigger since `#divA` and `#divB` are no descendant elements of `#divC`.