# CSS hover sub div background color change

Tags: html, css

I have this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98MDb/1/), and what I am trying to do is when you mouse over each div section, it only changes the background for that section. Is there any way I can do that without having it change the background for everything? When I mouse over `.two`, the `.one:hover` gets fired. how can I make it fire `.two` and not `.one` when I mouse over `.two`?

**CSS:**

```
div.one:hover, div.two:hover, div.three:hover{
    background-color: #69aeea;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="one">
    Text 1
    <div class="two">
        Text 2
        <div class="three">Text 3</div>
        <div class="three">Text 3</div>
        <div class="three">Text 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        Text 2
        <div class="three">Text 3</div>
        <div class="three">Text 3</div>
        <div class="three">Text 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is something like this acceptable? http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyblalock/98MDb/2/

Comment: No, that doesn't highlight the whole section. If you hover over `.one` it should highlight `.one`, `.two` and `.three`. If you hover over `.two` it should highlight `.two` and `.three` as a group.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing Hover event of a Div triggering on parent Div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364511/preventing-hover-event-of-a-div-triggering-on-parent-div)

Comment: You can if you change your HTML http://jsfiddle.net/98MDb/26/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't access the parent of an element in CSS. Meaning, that if you hover over a child element, you can't set the background of its parent. You'll have to use javascript to achieve what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`:hover` is triggered all the way up to the root parent (typically `<body>`), so you can't trigger it only on the child when you have `:hover` states on the parent.

What you need to do is isolate the parts you actually want to show a hover state, which in this case I accomplished by wrapping the text in a `<span>`. This will keep the `:hover` state isolated from the other children of that parent.

```
<div class="one">
  <span>Text 1</span>
  <div class="two">
    <span>Text 2</span>
    <div class="three"><span>Text 3</span></div>
...
```

Then target specifically in the CSS: *(The `>` character selects a direct descendent of a parent)*

```
div > span:hover {
  background-color: #69aeea;
}
```

You can then do different colors based on the level like so:

```
div.one > span:hover {
  background-color: #69aeea;
}
div.two > span:hover {
  background-color: #ae69ea;
}
div.three > span:hover {
  background-color: #aeea69;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/8uetm/