# Hover triggered after select list is displayed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div which has a hover function:

```
d = $("<div></div>");
d.hover(function() {        
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({
        'margin-left' : '-250px'
    }, 250, function () {
    });
}, function() {
    $('input').blur();
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({
        'margin-left' : '-10px'
    }, 250, function () {
    });
});
$('body').append(d);
```

In this div I create a pull down menu dynamically. I use it this way

```
box3 = $("<p></p>");
box3.val('Create');
box3.html(  '<u>All attributes</u><br>'+                        
            '<select id="attSelect"></select><BR>'


);      

d.append(box3);
```

Afterwards I fill the select with options.

Now when the select list is show by clicking on the pull down button of the select menu, the second function of the hover is triggered. This is because the mouse ain't no more "over" the div.

How can I prevent the div hover function from being activated after I try to select something in deselect?

Comment: Your answer is here. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364511/preventing-hover-event-of-a-div-triggering-on-parent-div)

Comment: would be great if you can provide a fiddle..