# Is there a selector to only affect the innermost :hover match with CSS only?

Tags: html, css, hover

For a feature to manage custom layouts, I've created a little wizard with zone indication, to offer a chance on seeing which zone you're editing.

Since it's a nested layout, all containers have the same CSS class values. In order to only issue the innermost element I've written a short piece of JavaScript code. To be precise, it's this:

```
$outermostContainer.on("mousemove", function(event) {
    var $t = $(event.target).closest("table.dashboardLayoutOutline");
    $layoutWizardTables.removeClass("hovering");
    $t.addClass("hovering");
});
```

Sample case:

http://jsfiddle.net/w0sw9510/ (The solution is correct if you hover one of the child elements and the parent element does not have a yellow border, while if you hover the outer element only that will receive a yellow border)

Is this really a case where I can't do something with CSS only?

I somehow can't imagine I'm the only one who has a use for this.

I've looked into W3C + mozilladocs for CSS 2/3 selectors and no selector I've seen appeared to handle the case I need.

These days I mainly do backend, so I hope there's one of you who knows a trick for me.

<sub>Duplicate questions: While this problem is similar to my issue, I did not find it while searching because of its title. I am just going to leave it here so others will find their answer too in case they use the same search words.</sub>

Comment: You mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/w0sw9510/1/ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing Hover event of a Div triggering on parent Div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364511/preventing-hover-event-of-a-div-triggering-on-parent-div)

Comment: @Abhitalks No, sadly not. the layout may be depth(n). Thus that css won't work then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible with just CSS, because when a child element is hovered the parent element is hovered too (and `pointer-events: none` doesn't help). However JavaScript makes it pretty simple:

```js
$('.zone').on('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('hovering', e.type === 'mouseover');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.zone {
    margin: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
}

.zone.hovering {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zone" id="parent" style='background-color: orange;'>
    <div class="zone" id="child1" style='background-color: red;'>a</div>
    <div class="zone" id="child2" style='background-color: blue;'>b</div>
</div>
```

Well, it's actually possible to do this in just CSS, but the solutions are not very flexible and generic, because it depends on the background color of the parent container:

```css
.zone {
    margin: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
}

.zone:hover {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}

.zone > .parent-border {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px; left: -5px; bottom: -5px; right: -5px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

.zone > .zone {
    z-index: 2;
}

.zone > .zone:hover ~ .parent-border {
    border: 5px orange solid;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="zone" id="parent" style='background-color: orange;'>
    <div class="zone" id="child1" style='background-color: red;'>a</div>
    <div class="zone" id="child2" style='background-color: blue;'>b</div>
    <div class="parent-border"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: meh. such a shame it doesn't work without js. i like your js solution better because i don't need to do reference tracking and manual toggles. Thanks!

Comment: *Well*... It's actually possible without JS, just it's not going to be the generic solution, because it sort of depends on container color.

Comment: I added CSS solution too, in case you want to take a look.

Comment: haha wow. while this certainly is a very creative solution, in my case i'd rather use the javascript instead because the other one would be weird mainteance wise. Thanks for trying though. Good idea though for someone else who really really really wants the solution to be css only

Comment: That is one *hack* of a solution :)

Comment: I would also go with javascript myself in this case :)